# kubectl get status of pods and grep on status tab by anything other than Running

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

Currently running following command to get status on pods:

```
kubectl -n kube-system get pods -o wide
```

Would like to grep or ack out on STATUS column and only show anything thats not running.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about `kubectl get pods --field-selector=status.phase!=Running` (maybe depending on the Kubernetes version you are using)